# SQL Server Management Studio won't open

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I try to open SQL Server Management Studio, it makes that windows 10 "beep" sound, and instantly closes. I am not able to open any `.sql` files too, it does the same thing. Reinstall did not helped at all.

I was doing some code, then decided to go and have a relaxing bath, and when I came back, the program did not start anymore. Does taking a bath can cause this kind of software error? Did anybody have the same issue?

Comment: No, a bath won't cause that problem; I've had many a washes since I installed SSMS and it's still working fine. It will have been something else you did prior to having the bath, that you did on the PC, such as an installation, update, etc. "That windows 10 'beep'" doesn't really mean much, but I would expect an error of some kind. Have you had a look in the event viewer for any errors?

Comment: Have a look in the Event Viewer for an error. It's quite likely something is logged there.

Comment: The windows 10 beep is sound is like when you are trying to open something, and it needs admin privilege, it makes that sound.  In the event viewer, under the applications and service logs i dont find anything such as MSSQL or SQL or any type of that.

Comment: The new version is horrible. But then again your question is not great either. What version you're using... what you've actually tried... less about your bath... this is all in the community guidelines. The reason I care is I'm having the same problem, and I suspect it might be for the same reason.

Comment: There's nothing in the Event Log, in my case. Only thing that works is uninstall|reinstall.

Comment: Could it be https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/237086/5203?

Comment: You really made me laugh. Here's 10 rep points for that. Not everyone here on SO wants to keep things professional only - some of us still needs a good laughter here and there.